# Number of cyclic subgroups of the alternating group $A_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Find the number of cyclic subgroups groups of the alternating group $A_8$.

I don't know how to even begin approaching this question. Is there a faster way to do this besides explicitly list each and every cyclic subgroup?

Comment: There are some ways to speed up the counting.  Note that any cyclic subgroups must have order dividing the order of $A_8$.  Of course counting all the elements of a particular order overcounts the number of cyclic subgroups of that order, because sometimes different elements generate the same cyclic subgroup.  But this is fairly easy to account for.

Answer (score 3):

I can tell you how to begin approaching the problem. All of them will involve combinatorial counting arguments. The cycle decomposition types that can occur should be listed first: the cyclic permutations of  odd order namely, 7, 5 and 3. Then  non-cyclic permutations of type $6+2,4+4, 4+2, 2+2, 5+3,3+3, 3+2+2,

Now you have to deal with each kind. In each kind count how many elements are there; then check if the cyclic subgroups generated by them have intersections or not; this is the trickiest part.  I'll do this for the easiest kind and leave the others to you.

There are $6!\times 8$ cyclic permutations of order 7. The cyclic subgroups generated by each of them will use 6 elements, and they can have only the identity element in common. So the number of cyclic subgroups of $A_8$ consisting of $7$-cycles is $6!\times8/6=960$.

Comment: can you also give a hint how to compute non-cyclic permutations? for example 4+4?